# Getting value from Alias name of DB connection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 connections with Aliases:

Alias:

```
C01556 connection with table User
C02557 connection with table User
C03558 connection with table User
```

i would like to know, whether is possible to make insert to table User, using as value substring from connection Alias name.
let´s say:

```
insert into 'User'(name, surname, id) values('John', 'Connor', ?)
```

? - `id value` should be substring of each alias started from  4th position(556 in first case, 557 in second case... )

is it possible?

Thanks